# JShell no longer prints output on next line after JDK update

Tags: java, jshell

Before updating JDK, any output in JShell would be automatically printed onto the next line. However, after updating, all the outputs are immediately printed onto the same line. This makes it completely unreadable and borderline unusable when dealing with longer outputs. How can I make it print the output onto the next line again?

Edit: I am using OpenJDK 11.0.9 2020-10-20 on Linux Mint.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could precise that JDK you updated to, for I don't have the issue with OpenJDK 14 (build 36).

Comment: I'm currently using OpenJDK 11.0.9 2020-10-20 on Linux Mint. Although I had this same issue when I used OpenJDK 14 on Windows running WSL as well. It's actually the sole reason I'm using OpenJDK 11 instead of 14, because OpenJDK did not have this issue previously.

Comment: Can confirm, but only with `<`, not in interactive mode. Note how it also omits the line break after the final `jshell>` prompt

Comment: Ok, I have the same thing when reading from a file using OpenJDK 14 (build 36).
Note that I have blank lines between statements tho.
I think we should investigate whether it's a feature or a bug introduced recently...